# How to ring bell while the phone is on phone in Android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, clock, telephonymanager

I am making a Clock APP,there is a select in setting that whether remind althrough the phone is on phone!

I get the "CallState" : `int callState =mTelephonyManager.getCallState();`

and get "isRemindInCall" by user's select

and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

then:`if(callState==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE||isRemindInCall){
                   ......
       }`

but not work!

Comment: you can use media player to play any audio while phone is on

Comment: Yeah,I do ,but the aduio dont play  while phone is on

Comment: @Anjali It only play while phone is not on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define mediaplayer to stream_music not notification nor alarm. To define this write this line after declaring your media player:

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```